# Stuck on JavaScript logic for properly looping through JSON objects using fetch and modifying parameters

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api, astrojs

I have a JSON file with the following data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bitcoin (BTC)",
        "url": "https://openapiv1.coinstats.app/coins/bitcoin" ,
        "quantity": .15
    },
    {
        "name": "Ethereum (ETH)",
        "url": "https://openapiv1.coinstats.app/coins/ethereum" ,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Solana (SOL)",
        "url": "https://openapiv1.coinstats.app/coins/solana" ,
        "quantity": 5
    }
]
```

Using the Astro framework, I'm attempting to loop through the objects in that file and output the data into simple styled HTML cards for a very rudimentary investment portfolio tracker as a fun learning project. For brevity's sake, I won't display all of the code structure but I can import the JSON file and display its data easily enough using this logic:

```
{
    holdingData.map ((holdingData) => {
        return (
            <PortCard
                name={holdingData.name}
                quantity={holdingData.quantity}
                price={APIprice}
            />
        )
    })
}
```

The part that's tripping me up however is the last property, price. I want to load the price of that particular asset (pulling the data from the API url listed for each object in the JSON file) at the time of page loading. Currently, I'm using the logic below to do so using fetch:

```
let APIfetch = await fetch(APIurl);
let APIresponse = await APIfetch.json();
let APIdata = APIresponse.price;
let APIprice = APIdata.toLocaleString("en-US", {style: "currency", currency: "USD"});
```

And, specifically, I can't sort out how to pass the variable APIurl for each iteration within the  map method.

```
let APIurl = holdingData.url;
```

I've tried all kinds of different ways of implementing that key piece of data but none are working. I'm sure that my basic JavaScript knowledge is very lacking here and I'm missing some fundamental understanding of JS logic.

If anyone can help clarify what I'm missing in this equation and point me in the right direction, it would be truly appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you having a problem with the asynchronous code that you want to map to UI? Does [this Astro data fetching guide](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/data-fetching/) help?

Comment: You've to use useState to store prices in an object and create a function that loop through the json to make the api requests for the prices and set them to the useState. Use useEffect to run this function on each page refresh. Use loader logic to render something else until all api calls are complete and data has arrived. Finally render the price results and the data on to the component.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can modify the API url inside a map function. Since it is asynchronous. Your url might get overwritten before the next iteration begins.

You could try [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

You have to create an array of API calls and use `Promise.all()` to execute them. After all promises are resolved, you can access data of each holding.

Something like below.

```js
const fetchData = async (holdings) => {
  const promises = holdings.map(async (holding) => {
    const response = await fetch(holding.url);
    const data = await response.json();
    return { ...holding, price: data.price };
  });

  const updatedHoldings = await Promise.all(promises);
  return updatedHoldings;
};
```

You can call the function like below

```js
fetchData(holdingData).then((updatedHoldings) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {updatedHoldings.map((holding) => (
        <PortCard
          name={holding.name}
          quantity={holding.quantity}
          price={holding.price}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});
```